# Magento 2 - Admin grid from file collection

Tags: magento2, admin, grid, uicomponent, di

I am actually trying to create a really simple grid (for now) listing files from server.
The collection work well, I take as example `Magento_Backup` module but for the grid the module is using the old way with class and not the `UI components`.

My collection class `\Foo\Bar\Model\Log\Collection` is extending `\Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Filesystem` to construct file collection.

I defined a new type in my `di.xml`

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="foo_bar_log_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">Foo\Bar\Model\Log\Collection</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Here is my `ui_component` named `foo_bar_log_listing.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">foo_bar_log_listing.foo_bar_log_listing_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">foo_bar_log_listing.foo_bar_log_listing_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">foo_bar_log_columns</item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="foo_bar_log_listing_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">foo_bar_log_listing_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">code</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">code</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">code</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sticky" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <bookmark name="bookmarks"/>
        <columnsControls name="columns_controls"/>
        <filterSearch name="fulltext"/>
        <filters name="listing_filters" />
        <paging name="listing_paging"/>
    </listingToolbar>
    <columns name="foo_bar_log_columns">
        <column name="code">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Code</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="file">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">>
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">File</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Here is my collection class

```
<?php

namespace Foo\Bar\Model\Log;

use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface;

class Collection extends FilesystemCollection
{

    /**
     * Filenames regex filter
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_allowedFilesMask = '/^[a-z0-9\.\-\_]+[bar]\.log/i';
    /**
     * @var \Foo\Bar\Helper\Log $logHelper
     */
    private $logHelper;
    /**
     * @var \Foo\Bar\Helper\Adminhtml\Log $adminLogHelper
     */
    private $adminLogHelper;

    public function __construct(
        EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
        \Foo\Bar\Helper\Log $logHelper,
        \Foo\Bar\Helper\Adminhtml\Log $adminLogHelper
    ) {
        $this->logHelper      = $logHelper;
        $this->adminLogHelper = $adminLogHelper;
        parent::__construct($entityFactory);

        /** @var string $logDirectory */
        $logDirectory = $this->logHelper->getLogDirectoryPath();

        $this->setCollectRecursively(true);
        $this->addTargetDir($logDirectory);
    }

    /**
     * @param string $filename
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function _generateRow($filename)
    {
        /** @var array $row */
        $row = parent::_generateRow($filename);
        $row = $this->adminLogHelper->generateRow($row);

        return $row;
    }
}
```

I understand that the `dataSource` is refering my `\Foo\Bar\Log\Collection` class with his arguments and for basics entities it is a `VirtualType` of `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult`

So my questions are
- Is it possible to create a file listing grid with UI Component as basic entities ?
- Which classes do I have to use in `di.xml` / `foo_bar_log_listing.xml` classes ?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show your module.

Comment: I just edited my question to add the `Collection` class ? Which part of the module do you need ?

Comment: @MatthéoGeoffray Could you help me with http://stackoverflow.com/q/43344902/1616003

Comment: @Muk In your case the `var/log` path had to be returned by `$logDirectory = $this->logHelper->getLogDirectoryPath();` or any other function / class in the Collection class

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is what you need.
All files path are relative to the `[Namespace]/[Module]` folder.
First, the layout handle for your action:  `view/adminhtml/layout/foo_bar_index.xml` (make sure the name matches the route)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="styles"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="foo_bar_listing"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Now the ui component `view/adminhtml/ui_component/foo_bar_listing.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">foo_bar_listing.foo_bar_listing_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">foo_bar_listing.foo_bar_listing_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">foo_bar_columns</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array"><!-- define buttons you need above the list. you may skip this -->
            <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New Foo Bar</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/new</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="foo_bar_listing_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">[Namespace]\[Module]\Ui\DataProvider\FooBarDataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">foo_bar_listing_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">filename_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">filename_id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sticky" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <bookmark name="bookmarks"/>
        <columnsControls name="columns_controls"/>
        <filterSearch name="fulltext"/><!-- skip this if you don't want full text search-->
        <filters name="listing_filters">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridFilters</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">filters</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">foo_bar_listing.foo_bar_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.filters</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">foo_bar_listing.foo_bar_listing.listing_top.listing_filters</item>
                        <item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="visible" xsi:type="string">foo_bar_listing.foo_bar_listing.listing_top.bookmarks:current.columns.${ $.index }.visible</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <filterInput name="filename_id">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">filename_id</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Module Name</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </filterInput><!-- additional filters go here -->
        </filters>
        <paging name="listing_paging"/>
    </listingToolbar>
    <columns name="foo_bar_columns">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">foo_bar_listing.foo_bar_listing.foo_bar_columns.actions</item>
                        <item name="target" xsi:type="string">applyAction</item>
                        <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="0" xsi:type="string">edit</item>
                            <item name="1" xsi:type="string">${ $.$data.rowIndex }</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="controlVisibility" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="appendTo" xsi:type="string">foo_bar_listing.foo_bar_listing.listing_top.columns_controls</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">foo_bar_listing.foo_bar_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="root" xsi:type="string">columns.${ $.index }</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.${ $.storageConfig.root}</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <column name="filename_id"><!-- feel free to change the column name -->
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/column</item>
                </item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">File name</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column> <!-- additional columns here -->
        <actionsColumn name="actions" class="[Namespace]\[Module]\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\FooBarActions"><!-- Skip this if your module does not have any actions -->
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">200</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">actions</item>
                    <item name="align" xsi:type="string">left</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Action</item>
                    <item name="data_type" xsi:type="string">actions</item>
                    <item name="filterable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="sortable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </actionsColumn>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

(please don't ask me to explain what every tag does. I barely know what a few of them mean).

Now the controller action for your grid page.

`Controllers/Adminhtml/FooBar/Index.php` (make sure the filename matches your route).

```
<?php
namespace [Namespace]\[Module]\Controller\Adminhtml\FooBar;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Index extends Action
{
    /**
     * page factory reference
     *
     * @var PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    )
    {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    /**
     * run index action
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $pageResult = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $pageResult->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(__('Your Page title'));
        $pageResult->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('FooBar List'));
        $this->_setActiveMenu('Your menu id here') //can skip this
            ->_addBreadcrumb(
                __('Your Module Name'),
                __('Your Module Name')
            )->_addBreadcrumb(
                __('FooBar List'),
                __('FooBar List')
            );
        return $pageResult;
    }
}
```

the data provider for the grid: `Ui/DataProvider/FooBarDataProvider.php`

```
<?php
namespace [Namespace]\[Module]\Ui\DataProvider;

use Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider;
use [Namespace]\[Module]\Model\FooBar\CollectionFactory;

/**
 * Class ProductDataProvider
 */
class FooBarDataProvider extends AbstractDataProvider
{
    /**
     * foobar collection
     *
     * @var \[Namespace]\[Module]\Model\FooBar\Collection
     */
    protected $collection;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AddFieldToCollectionInterface[]
     */
    protected $addFieldStrategies;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AddFilterToCollectionInterface[]
     */
    protected $addFilterStrategies;

    /**
     * Construct
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @param string $primaryFieldName
     * @param string $requestFieldName
     * @param CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
     * @param array $meta
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
        $this->collection = $collectionFactory->create();
    }

    /**
     * Get collection
     *
     * @return \[Namespace]\[Module]\Model\FooBar\Collection
     */
    public function getCollection()
    {
        return $this->collection;

    }

    /**
     * Get data
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getData()
    {
        if (!$this->getCollection()->isLoaded()) {
            $this->getCollection()->load();
        }
        return $this->getCollection()->toArray();
    }
}
```

the class for adding actions to each row, only if you need it.

`Ui/Component/Listing/Columns/FooBarActions.php`

```
<?php
namespace [Namespace]\[Module]\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns;

use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Column;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;

class FooBarActions extends Column
{
    /**
     * @var UrlInterface
     */
    protected $urlBuilder;

    /**
     * @param ContextInterface $context
     * @param UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory
     * @param UrlInterface $urlBuilder
     * @param array $components
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        UiComponentFactory $uiComponentFactory,
        UrlInterface $urlBuilder,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
        parent::__construct($context, $uiComponentFactory, $components, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Prepare Data Source
     *
     * @param array $dataSource
     * @return array
     */
    public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
    {
        if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
            //this is just a demo, it might not work on your instance.
            foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as &$item) {
                $item[$this->getData('name')]['edit'] = [
                    'href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(
                        '[module]/controller/edit',
                        ['id' => $item['id']]
                    ),
                    'label' => __('Edit'),
                    'hidden' => false,
                ];

            }
        }
        return $dataSource;
    }
}
```

your collection class looks fine, just add this method in it.

```
/**
 * @param $field
 * @param $direction
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Data\Collection
 */
public function addOrder($field, $direction)
{
    return $this->setOrder($field, $direction);
}
```

That's all I have for now, it this does not solve your problem it should at least push your forward.
I left some comments in the code, read them and take the necessary actions.

Comment: forgot to mention that the full text search does not work properly for me.

Comment: Huge thank you the only thing missing to my initial development was the correct `DataProvider` I was still using the entity default one. I validate your answer ;)

Comment: For the bounty I have to wait 20 hours so I validate it later

Comment: NO problem. Just one more thing. I forgot to tell you that you don't need to declare your collection in di.xml anymore.

Comment: Yes I already deleted it because of the new `FooBarDataProvider` directly declared in the ui component file. Thank  you.

Comment: This looks like a very fine example of using the component for the admin grid. I might use it too on my Magento 2. However, do you know if the other way works too, with the di.xml and without using the component, only layout?

Comment: I know how it works. It's very similar to how it's done in Magento 1. But I won't recommend it, It may go away soon.

Comment: where does the collectionFactory come from? I'm not sure/understanding where it comes from :)