# Custom Grid in magento 2 without Form

Tags: magento2, admin, grid

How to create Admin **Grid Without Form** in magento 2 . I don't need form i Just Want Grid with my content I am referring to Cache or Re indexing kind of Grid is this possible to achieve that I tried with rendering but its not done Can you please help me on this to achieve that feature

Screenshot for reference below:
[image]

**Magento\SampleForm\view\adminhtml\ui_component\sampleform_form.xml**

```
<listing  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Ui/etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
  <dataSource name="sampleform_form_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\SampleForm\Model\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">sampleform_form_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">entity_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource> 


 <columns name="mysampleform">
    <column name="entity_id">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">entity_id</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>

     <column name="color">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">color</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>

    <column name="title">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">title</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </column>

     </columns>

 </listing>
```

**Magento\SampleForm\view\adminhtml\layout\sampleform_index_index.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <title>
            Test Content By Ankit
        </title>
        <css src="Magento_SampleForm::css/color-select.css"/>
    </head>
    <update handle="styles"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="sampleform_form"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

In `Magento 1` as in `Magento 2`, grids and forms are two different things.
You can create a grid without a form and a form without a grid. The two are often linked but this is not an obligation.

To create a grid in Magento 2 you have to use the listing `UI Component`.
Here you can find more informations about them :

- http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/ui-components/ui-component.html
- http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/ui-components/ui-listing-grid.html

If you want an example on how to create one you can take a look at CMS pages in `Magento_Cms` module.
You have to create a ui_component : `magento/module-cms/view/adminhtml/ui_component/cms_page_listing.xml`

Here you can find a complete explanation https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/97891/33619

Comment: thankf for reply but i dont want grid like below Screen shot i want only cache or reindex grid https://www.screencast.com/t/2dXVT8mlIQE

Comment: Yes that is the same answer, you have to use `ui_component` anyway. The only thing that will change is the DataProvider class.

Comment: I added screen what i need i updated my question please check

Comment: In the `ui_component` declaration you don't have to add buttons, search bar, etc you can do a simple `ui_component` with only column and DataProvider class. But you definitly have to use `ui components` ;)

Comment: i tried this sample module  https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/blob/master/sample-module-form-uicomponent/README.md but i am getting error Fatal error: Method Magento\Ui\TemplateEngine\Xhtml\Result::__toString() must not throw an exception, caught Error: Call to a member function addFieldToFilter() on null in E:\Personal\Project\xampp\htdocs\magento2\vendor\magento\module-ui\Component\Wrapper\UiComponent.php on line 0

Comment: I fixed that above error now i am able to see the static content How to add column now i referred cms_page_listing.xml but unable to add can you please help on this

Comment: You add columns with the nodes `<columns><column/></columns>`. Here you can find an example : https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Cms/view/adminhtml/ui_component/cms_page_listing.xml#L163

Comment: :i updated my question with solution what you suggested But its not showing column . Its showing only head content which i declated in xml

Comment: I got the grid now now can you please tell me how to get Data inside that grid same as like cache grid for reference

Comment: You have to use a DataProvider. Here is a tuto explaining DataProvider and grid : https://www.maximehuran.fr/en/create-adminhtml-grid-with-magento-2/ and there is a question I asked about custom DataProvider : http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/150283/33619. Please also check the DataProvider declaration in `magento/module-cms/etc/di.xml:59` and the class of the DataProvider `\Magento\Cms\Model\Page\DataProvider`

Comment: I tried same as cms one but unable to implement in my module now my module it look like https://www.screencast.com/t/GhXjCp0ZXGoj i referred cache.xml also but no luck can you please help on this

Comment: i checked dataprovider for cms block its reading data from database but in my case i do not have database form i want to read Magento cache is reading data like https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Store/etc/cache.xml

Comment: Your DataProvider is a collection with a table in database ?

Comment: Did you check that link ? It is how to use a custom DataProvider : http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/150283/33619. In that case it reads file from server but you can easily change.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52439/discussion-between-magento12345-and-mattheo-geoffray).

Comment: Did you checked ?